# Twitter Api for .NETApplications

Tags: twitter

Can any one suggest me to best C# twitter api for developing application with twitter api?. I want all the advance functionality of twitter in my application.

Comment: I'd suggest marking one of the other, available libraries like Twitterizer or LINQ to Twitter as answer as TweetSharp has disappeared without a trace (the developer took it down). A shame as TweetSharp was indeed superior to them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

May I humbly suggest [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/).  It has full support for the API including the Search API and updates are released as soon as possible to address changes in the twitter API.  (for instance, it already supports the upcoming GeoLocation APIs).

It's open source (MIT license), so you can use it free for pretty much anything you want.

**Disclosure**: I'm a project owner.

Comment: Don't bother: the project has been taken down without a trace.

Answer (score 4):

[Twitterizer](https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer)

> Twitterizer is a .NET class library that provides an easy-to-use interface for the Twitter web api. It is written for developers. It's features are easy to discover and follow a consistent design pattern.  http://www.twitterizer.net

Comment: Tried this but made more progress with tweetsharp - better docs there

Comment: FWIW: I answered this in 2009 when the project was in full swing. It looks like now it's no longer being supported by its author.

Answer (score 3):

[LINQ to Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/),  if your app is LINQ-enabled.

"LINQ to Twitter is a LINQ Provider for the Twitter micro-blogging service. It uses standard LINQ syntax for queries and includes method calls for changes via the Twitter API."

I haven't used this myself, just found it when browsing and passing it on. It's interesting that if you search with the [#linqtotwitter](http://twitter.com/#search?q=%23linqtotwitter) hashtag, you can see all the test tweets, which all start with "Ç".

Answer (score 1):

Kindly follow the below link to get latest API for Twitter
[Latest Twitter API](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/)